# display a vimeo frame in a view

Tags: views

I have a field that holds a vimeo video ID, I'm trying to display this content using a view where I'm rewriting this field, but the markup is getting stripped out.

```
<iframe src="//player.vimeo.com/video/[view_field_id]" width="WIDTH" height="HEIGHT" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

How can I display a vimeo iframe in drupal using views?

Comment: Drupal 7 or 8???

Answer (score 2):

As per this support request in Views issue queue: [Views: Rewrite field, strips some HTML tags (SOLUTION/WORKAROUND FOUND FOR STYLE TAG)](https://www.drupal.org/node/853880) Views strips out certain tags. It does this using [filter_xss_admin](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/filter_xss_admin/7), which if you look at that API entry calls [filter_xss](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/filter_xss/7), passing in an array of allowed tags. `iframe` is not one of those unfortunately.

So I think that you might need to do a workaround. I would look at two ways of doing this:

1. Rewrite the outut in a Views template. You click on `Theme:Information` at the bottom of the advanced pane in Views UI and you would select the theme file for the Vimeo field. More at [An Intro to Drupal Views Templates and Theming](https://www.ostraining.com/blog/drupal/views-templates/)
2. Create your own theme function to output the iframe. Enable [Views PHP](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_php) and call the theme function from a rewritten Views field.

Answer (score 0):

you can create view custom template file and than add iframe and in ifram you can print view fields and i know you are entering just vimeo link in back-end and in views thats field link will display so you can print that field in iframe in view template file.